# Defining a range using a variable integer in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So here is my problem. I know we can define a range in VBA, say for example like 
Range("A1:A300"). Now say I have some integer x. I want the range from A1 to Ax. How can I write this in a code? Range("A1:Ax") clearly does not work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6945949/11683

Comment: Oh gee thanks a a lot for the down vote just say it's a duplicate and I would have deleted the question

Comment: GSerg, that "dupe", by the way, is way over-complicated for this _specific_ need. It also won't handle `AA` thru whatever the current maximum column is :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo I did not vote for close as duplicate, otherwise there would be a close vote on the question. The question is not about Excel or ranges, it is about concatenating a string and a number. This question, while arguably not welcome on SO considering all the "please get a book on the language basics" comments these questions have generated, has been answered plenty of times, I simply dumped a link to the first one I found that shows the technique, with the added bonus of being in Excel context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be something like:

```
Range("A1:A" & CStr(x))
```

The `CStr` function will turn an integer into a string though I think you can actually just leave it off in later versions of Excel:

```
Range("A1:A" & x)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the anchor cell then extend:

```
range("A1").resize(300)
```