# Function that returns a string representing a worksheet row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a function (named `CreateRowRange`) that will take a string having the form "$A$5" and produce a string having the form "A5:M5". Similarly, if I call the function with "$A$14", it will return "A14:M14". I have an Excel spreadsheet with data in columns "A" through "M". I found a similar post on Stack Overflow ([Concatenating Variables Into String to be Set to a Range in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945949/concatenating-variables-into-string-to-be-set-to-a-range-in-vba)), but it seems overly complicated. The code written thus far for the function is:

```
Function CreateRowRange(CellAddress) As String
    CreateRowRange = Range(CellAddress).Row
End Function
```

Comment: I think I just sort of addressed this in your previous question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should return what you want:

```
Function CreateRowRange(CellAddress) As String
    CreateRowRange = Range(Range(CellAddress),Range("M" & Range(CellAddress).Row)).Address(False,False)
End Function
```

Comment: @PublicTechie2015 Feel free to accept either answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, try this:

```
Function CreateRowRange(CellAddress as String) as String
    CreateRowRange = Replace(CellAddress, "$", "")
    CreateRowRange = CreateRowRange & ":" & Replace(CreateRowRange, "A", "M")
End Function
```

Comment: This is nice, I got caught by the OPs use of range and forgot that the input and output are both strings.

Answer (score 0):

Excel already has built in properties and methods to modify ranges. If you're going to use it like

```
Range(CreateRowRange("$A$14")).Value = "X"
```

then you can achieve the same thing with

```
Range("$A$14").Resize(1,13).Value = "X"
```

If you're building a formula like

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(" & CreateRowRange("$A$14") & ")"
```

then you can achieve the same thing with

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(" & Range("A14").Resize(1,13).Address(0,0) & ")"
```

The `0,0` part makes the address relateive - no dollar signs